# UISegmentedControl Font change IOS7

Tags: xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I stumbled on a UISegmentedControl and i want to adjust the font size, went over several tutorials but still not able to fix it since all the examples look different of what i have and no font option in the InterfaceBuilder, so how and actually where do i add the font criteria? Thanks for your help. This is what i have:

```
- (void)valueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)segment

{   
if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
    [self getlistInformationbyIdPerson:self.person.id_person withInformationType:1 withCompletion:^{
        [self.personConnectedInformationTableView reloadData];

    }];
}
else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
    [self getlistInformationbyIdPerson:self.person.id_person withInformationType:3 withCompletion:^{
        [self.personConnectedInformationTableView reloadData];

    }];
}
else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2){
    [self getlistInformationyIdPerson:self.person.id_person withInformationType:2 withCompletion:^{
        [self.personConnectedInformationTableView reloadData];

    }];
}
}
```

and i have this one:

```
- (NSString *)noSegmentedControlDataLabelForSegment:(NSInteger)aSegment andCelebrity:(NSString *)aCelebrity
{

NSString *noDataMessage;
NSString *segmentText

switch (aSegment) {
    case 0:
        segmentText = @"list1";
        break;
    case 1:
        segmentText = @"list2";
        break;
    case 2:
        segmentText = @"list3";
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

noDataMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"We are sorry to inform you that our dataBase dosen't contain any information"];

return noDataMessage;

}
```

and this one in the .h

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segment;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Courier", size: 12.0) {
        print("Font Available")
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font]
        self.segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    else {
        print("Font not available")
    }
}
```

Where `segmentControl` is `IBOutlet` of `UISegmentedControl`

If you want to use `SystemFont` then you don't have to unwrap the font value. In that case use below code

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName : font]
self.segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: it gives me an error: Use of undeclared identifier 'override'

Comment: The idea is you have to write this code, in my example I have added it in `viewDidLoad` method which is being overridden here.

Comment: thanks i added a version as you mentioned to the ViewDid Load and i worked:

Answer (score 0):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:8.0f];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font
                                                       forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[self.segment setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Adding this to the ViewDidLoad changed the font size for me, thanks for getting me on the right track Inder Kumar :)